# How can I count pairs when the columns are equal/not equal in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a dataset that I want to count when the pairs are equal **and** not equal, grouping by one column.  A toy dataset would look like this:

```
DECLARE @t Table (
    SampleNumber varchar(max),
    SampleType varchar(max),
    A varchar(max),
    B varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('B1','DD','PASS','FAIL'),
    ('B1','DS','PASS','FAIL'),
    ('B2','DD','PASS','PASS'),
    ('B2','DS','PASS','PASS'),
    ('B3','DD','NA','NA'),
    ('B3','DS','NA','PASS'),
    ('B4','DD','PASS','PASS'),
    ('B4','DS','PASS','FAIL')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

So for this dataset I would like the output to look something like this:

[image: NewOutput]
I will note that I have about many SampleNumbers (100+) and about 10 columns (e.g. A through J) that I need to roll the data up from so I was hoping to a flexible solution.

It would be horribly inefficient to split the SampleType into two temp tables (e.g. DD and DS) and join by SampleNumber.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using a `CASE` expression inside your `COUNT`/`SUM`?

Comment: Also, should `'NA'`,`'PASS` not be counted in both the Pass and NA rows in Disagree, or is the grouping based solely on the value of `A`?

Comment: Its just if the pairs (DD/DS) are equal (e.g. if B1 DD = B1 DS ). So B4 DD-DS in column A is equal (PASS=PASS) but B4 DD-DS in column B is not equal (PASS != FAIL)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IQ.A, SUM(IQ.X) as DD_AGREE, SUM(1 -IQ.X) AS DD_DIsagree
FROM
(SELECT A,CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END X FROM @t) IQ
GROUP BY IQ.A
UNION SELECT B, 0,0 FROM @T where B NOT IN(SELECT t2.A FROM @t t2)
```

Comment: I am thinking this gives the correct answer but for the wrong reason?  It should not check Column A vs Column B but instead Row1 Column A vs Row2 Column A, Row3 Column A vs Row4 Column A and so on.

Comment: I will change the data to show what I mean by making Row1 and Row2 of Column B both be Fail and they should agree.

Comment: in that case you will also need a row_number, or some sort of specified order, at the moment it isn't clear how the order of rows is determined